# Добавление в базу данных на одной странице

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день.
Подскажите пожалуйста  как добавлять в базу даных используя  всего одну страницу. Чтобы  была страница на которую выводится содержемое, снизу форма была добаввления  записей. После того как добавишь автоматически редиректило на страницу с  записями

```
if($_GET['action'] == 'add')
{
       if($_POST['do'] =='')
       {
        echo
        '
        <form action="?action=add" method="post" class="niceform">
        <fieldset>
        <dl>
            <dt><label>IP:</label></dt>
            <dd><input type="text" name="ip" id="" size="30 " /></dd>
        </dl>
        <dl class="submit">
            <input type="submit" name="do" id="submit" value="Добавить" />
        </dl>
        </fieldset>
        </form>
        ';
       }
       else
       {
          $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO equipment VALUES(".$_POST['ip'].")");
          if($result)
          {
              @header('../');
              echo
              '

              Новость успешно добавлена. <a href="?action=view_news">Перейти</a> к списку новостей.

              ';
          }
          else
          {
              echo
                '
                <div class="error_box">
                Возникла ошибка при записи в Базу Данных.
                </div>  
                ';

          }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

**do.php**

```
if(isset($_GET['action'])) {
    if($_GET['action'] == 'add') {
        if(!isset($_POST['do'])) {
            echo
            '
        <form action="do.php?action=add" method="post" class="niceform">
            <fieldset>
        <dl>
        <dt><label>IP:</label></dt>
        <dd><input type="text" name="ip" id="" size="30 " /></dd>
        </dl>
        <dl class="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="do" id="submit" value="Добавить" />
        </dl>
        </fieldset>
        </form>
        ';
        } else {
            $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO equipment VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ip'])."')");
            if($result) {
                header("Location: do.php?action=view_news"); // редайрект
                ...
            } else {
                die(mysql_error());
            }
        }
    }
}
```